# JOLT: select/change child by attribute

Tags: json, jolt

I'm new to JOLT and googled a lot (maybe using wrong search terms) but could not find an answer to my seemingly simple problem.
I want to change an attribute of a child which is identified by another attribute.

So I have this input:

```
{
  "Level0": {
    "Level-1": {
      "ID": 10,
      "Status": "OK",
    },
    "Level-2": {
      "ID": 20,
      "Status": "OK",
    },
    "Level-3": {
      "ID": 30,
      "Status": "OK",
    }
  }
}
```

and want to change the 'Status' value of the child with ID=20 so that this is the expected output:

```
{
  "Level0": {
    "Level-1": {
      "ID": 10,
      "Status": "OK",
    },
    "Level-2": {
      "ID": 20,
      "Status": "Running",
    },
    "Level-3": {
      "ID": 30,
      "Status": "OK",
    }
  }
}
```

I tried many variants with "modify-overwrite-beta" but could not get the desired result.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional within a **shift** transformation specification such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the outermost level 
        "*": {
          "ID": {
            "@": "&3.&2.&1", // replicate the ID's value
            "20": { "#Running": "&4.&3.Status" }, // express fixed value by prefixing it with #
            "*": { "@2,Status": "&4.&3.Status" } // if ID is not equal to 20, the keep the current value of the "Status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where the identifiers with *ampersands*( **&1**,**&2**... ) represent the name of the nodes received by going that much level up the tree respectively.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]